# Connecting to mysql running in container from host through perl DBI

Tags: mysql, docker, perl, containers, dbi

I am trying to connect to mysql running in container through perl script.

Container

```
1063b3f15b0f   mysql:latest            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 days ago   Up 3 days   0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   test_db
```

Connections works from host with tcp protocol
`mysql -P 3306 --protocol=tcp -u root -p`

But not sure how we can specify protocol with DBI in perl

```
use DBI;

my $driver = "mysql";
my $host = "127.0.0.1";
my $database = "users";
my $dsn = "DBI:$driver:database=$database,host=$host";
my $userid = "root";
my $password = "testpw";

my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $userid, $password ) or die $DBI::errstr;
```

Fails with error

```
DBI connect('database=users,host=127.0.0.1','root',...) failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) at update_db.pl line 10.
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) at update_db.pl line 10.
```

Can someone help here to crack it.?

Comment: Can you actually get in with the `mysql` client from the same machine? It's reaching the server with DBI, so the port must be correct. But it says you can't get in. That sounds like the grants in mysql are not correct.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify the protocol. The fact that you're connecting to "127.0.0.1" (rather than "localhost") is enough to ensure that DBI will connect over TCP instead of using a Unix socket (see [Connection Transport Protocols](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/transport-protocols.html) for details).

However, I suspect that your root user doesn't have permission to connect from just anywhere. What do you see if you run the following SQL:

```
select user, host from mysql.user where user = 'root';
```

The MySQL user module allows you to specify which hosts a user can connect from. A '%' in the `host` column will allow connections from any host. Otherwise you can only connect from certain hosts.